# Can I generate a form depending on the results of a view?

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-views, drupal-forms

I need to create a form which depends on the results of a view. I can generate it within the view and/or create a view template in order to do this....But how do I process it?

How do I connect my form/template generated form to a form_submission function?

When this custom/dynamic form is submitted I need to call some drupal functions to create some content in the site.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any way to do it in a view, but what I did was:
 - Create a form programatically, making only a hidden field for NIDS
 - Place my view next to that form using AJAX
 - When the view is updated I copy the results of the view to the NIDS field and submit the form (This reloads the page)
 - Form submission has 2 behaviours, 1 to re-generate the form when provided with NIDs, and other one for the actual form created by the NIDS result of my view.

Just in case this helps someone